# incorrect expected output from assembly loops

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am not getting the expected output. I have a loop that should continue 10x, then the second loop that should continue 10x times. Loops should print seperately

```
section .data
    msg1:   db  "first",10,0
    msg2:   db  "second",10,0
    len1:   equ $-msg1
    len2:   equ $-msg2
section .bss
    num resb    1    ;reserve 1 byte
section .text
    global main
main:
    mov [num], BYTE 10d ;num = 10
    loop:
    mov edx,    len1
    mov ecx,    msg1
    mov ebx,    1
    mov eax,    4
    int 80h
    dec BYTE [num]      ; num--
    cmp [num], BYTE 0
    jnz loop        ; jump if not equal to zero

    mov [num], BYTE 20d ; num = 20
    loop2:
    mov edx,    len2
    mov ecx,    msg2
    mov ebx,    1
    mov eax,    4
    int 80h
    sub [num], BYTE 2   ; num = num - 2
    cmp [num], BYTE 0
    ja loop2        ; jump if above 0

    mov eax,    1
    mov ebx,    0
    int 80h
```

I am getting
`first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
first
second
second
second
second
second
second
second
second
second
second
second`

but im expecting `first first first first first first first first first first second second second second second second second second second second`

I am new to assembly (NASM), what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your definition here:

```
section .data
msg1:   db  "first",10,0
msg2:   db  "second",10,0
len1:   equ $-msg1
len2:   equ $-msg2
```

Here you're saying that `msg1` includes all of the first message and the second message.

That should be

```
msg1:   db  "first",10,0
len1:   equ $-msg1

msg2:   db  "second",10,0
len2:   equ $-msg2
```